# Declarar parâmetro que não recebe valor

Tags: c#, sql

Na minha procedure existe 4 parametros, 3 deles são inseridos os valores, mas um outro (codMeioTransporte) ele recebe o valor em meio a um select que existe dentro da procedure.
Agora não sei como declarar esse parametro no código.

código:

```
public ActionResult Index(string cpf, string cnpj, DateTime dataFinal, int codMeioTransporte)
  {
      cadastroDAL dao = new cadastroDAL ();

      try
      {
            dao.FinalizarVigencia(cpf, cnpj, dataFinal, codMeioTransporte);
            ViewBag.sucesso = "1";
            return View(Index);
          
      }
      catch (Exception er)
      {
          ViewBag.Sucesso = "0";
          LogEventoController.RegistrarEventoPorException(er);
          return View();
      }
  }
```

o select que está no meio da proc

```
SELECT @codMeioTransporte = codigo FROM TransporteLoja
```

Após isso é feito um insert que usa o `@codMeioTransporte` como o código

Comment: Se não precisa receber valor de fora então não precisa ser um parâmetro.